# Escaping HTML Escape Characters

Tags: html, email, escaping, html-email, mailmerge

I'm writing an email, and I want to include some custom HTML formatting like:

`<p>Hello Friend</p><br><br>`

If I write the above directly in the email body, the email program will automatically escape out of characters like <, >, and &. resulting in the following:

`&lt;p&gt;Hello Friend&lt;/p&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;`

Is there a way to avoid or reverse this escaping?

The problem is also occurring with a Mail Merge type software called GovDelivery. I want to put HTML inside their "macros" but GovDelivery automatically escapes out of the characters making it impossible to have custom formats per email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email provider does this to prevent against [Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks and is most likely intentional behavior.

As a solution, most services that disable this behavior use [Markdown](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). That may result in similar behavior to what you want.

Comment: Helpful! Markdown language did not work but I now understand why.